# New objects on mogenerator

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mogenerator

Im new using Mogenerator (it looks great!). I just can't figure out how is the equivalent sentence to:
    NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription ...]

How should I create new objects in Mogen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual `NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription ...]` method will still work, otherwise `mogenerator` provides a `+ (id)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;` method which you'd call like:

```
NSMangedObject *mo = [MyModel insertInManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

To see any other methods `mogenerator` creates you can take a look at the `_MyModel.h` files it generates.

Comment: What Sherman Lo said. A little more background: you should prefer +[MyModel insertInManagedObjectContext:] since it's 1) typesafe 2) will break at compile time if you change your entity's name and 3) it's less to type.